# Initializer list not working xCode 4.4

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, xcode4.4

I'm trying to use an initializer list in XCode 4,

```
struct Vector2f
{
  float x,y;
  Vector2f():x(0.f),y(0.f){}
  Vector2f( float ix, float iy ):x(ix),y(iy){}
} ;
```

But I'm getting 7 compiler errors,

[image: errors]

So it looks like it thinks I'm doing some "bit-field" business, but I'm trying to use an initializer list!

The code file is marked as "C++ header" in the file properties, but it seems it's compiling as C?

Comment: Headers are not generally compiled on their own. Their content gets compiled when it is included in another file. Are you including this C++ header in a C file?

Comment: Included in an Objective-C (.m) file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see.  The file that was *including* this C++ source was a `.m` file -- ie it was being compiled as "Objective-C".

Renaming the `#include`ing file to `.mm` changes it's compilation mode to **Objective-C++**, then the compilation of the `Vector2f` C++ class is successful.

- The other error I got (when I changed `struct Vector2f` to `class Vector2f`)

> [Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588734/unknown-type-name-class-did-you-mean-class)