# How to use custom-typed arguments in blocks

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, objective-c-blocks

I have defined a callback block for a JSON service like so:

```
#import "JSONResult.h"
typedef void (^JSONResultHandler)(JSONResult*);
```

Obviously, the JSONResult typed argument is a custom type and its header file is included where this block is defined. Why do I then get the following error?

```
/Users/oyvind/code/_objc/JSONService.h:22:35: Unknown type name 'JSONResult'
```

Comment: if you command+click on the JSONResult part, does it take you to the class's definition?

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9633667/944634)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you importing your JSON service class in `JSONResult` too? Maybe you have a circular reference problem.

If you are importing the JSON service class in `JSONResult` and that import is absolutely necessary, try using forward declaration to import JSONResult in your .h:

```
@class JSONResult;

@interface SomeJSONService : NSObject

typedef void (^JSONResultHandler)(JSONResult*);

@end
```

Double check your imports and class names are OK too.

Comment: Circular reference was the culprit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have imported the `JSONResult.h` header correctly in `JSONService.h`:

```
#import "JSONResult.h"
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @S.L. Barth: Thanks, I reworded the answer.