# Include C++ and Objective C into Swift Framework

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to build a Swift framework that includes C++ and OpenCV Framework for iOS

As far as I understand we can't have a bridging header in framework, we have to deal with umbrella header.

My issue is that XCode is not processing C++ file as C++, with that kind of compiler error :
`Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?`
It also cannot find `<iostream>`

I currently have my umbrella that is including a objc wrapper for my C++ files.
What is the right way to do it ?

*Below my framework umbrella header*

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#else
    #ifndef FOUNDATION_EXPORT
        #if defined(__cplusplus)
            #include <iostream>
            #define FOUNDATION_EXPORT extern "C"
        #else
            #define FOUNDATION_EXPORT extern
        #endif
    #endif
#endif

#import "AGImageDescriptor.h"
#import "AGKitLib.h"
#import "Detector.h"
#import "Observable.h"
#import "Shooter.h"
#import "DocumentDetectedState.hpp"
#import "DocumentMatchState.hpp"
#import "GoodPerspectiveState.hpp"
#import "GoodPositionState.hpp"
#import "InactiveState.h"
#import "ReadyState.hpp"
#import "StartState.h"
#import "State.h"
#import "States.h"
#import "TextDetectedState.hpp"
#import "Tools.hpp"
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import "UIImage+OpenCV.h"

FOUNDATION_EXPORT double AGKitScanVersionNumber;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char AGKitScanVersionString[];
```

I am really not an C++ expert nor a C expert so I am probably missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors your are getting indicate that your umbrella header possibly includes C++ code, directly or indirectly.  In fact, I see a lot of `.hpp` files, which are probably C++ headers.  With Swift code being present in the framework, you cannot do that.  All C++ code must be confined to the Objective-C++ wrapper's implementation files (`.mm` extension, not `.m` used for Objective-C files).  Objective-C++ (`.mm`) files can used a mixture of C++ and Objective-C code and include the necessary C++ headers.

Here are some questions/answers that might help: [Unknown type name 'class'; did you mean 'Class'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588734/unknown-type-name-class-did-you-mean-class) and [Video processing with OpenCV in IOS Swift project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413951/video-processing-with-opencv-in-ios-swift-project/37427098#37427098)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That helped me a lot :) Indeed every C++ file should be declared inside the umbrella header. Thanks !

Comment: @Akhu can you update your question with the final umbrella header details.  I am also trying to do the same thing but have never heard of an umbrella header so have no idea where this even needs to go.  Thanks